# Solr Dataimport is not indexing excel file stored as BLOB in DB

Tags: solr

Hi I have configured Solr with TikaEntityprocessor to index BLOB type from DB. My problem is when the contents of an excel file is stored as BLOB in DB nothing gets indexed into SOLR.There is neither any exception thrown. Everything works fine when the BLOB field contains simple binary data.

Below is my data-config.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<dataConfig>
    <dataSource name="db" driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" 
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//x.x.x.x:1521/d11gr21" 
        user="dummy" password="dummy"/>
    <dataSource name="dastream" type="FieldStreamDataSource" />
    <document>
        <entity  name="messages" 
            query="select MSG_PK,MESSAGE from table1" dataSource="db">
            <field column ="MSG_PK" name ="id" />

            <entity name="message" dataSource="dastream" 
                processor="TikaEntityProcessor"
                url="message"
                dataField="messages.MESSAGE"
                format="text">

                <field column="text" name="mxMsg" />
            </entity>
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

**Update**
After indexing when I query, the output shows something like this :

```xml
<result name="response" numFound="1" start="0">
    <doc>
      <arr name="message">
        <str>oracle.sql.BLOB@121c39fa</str>
      </arr> 
      <int name="id">992</int>
      <arr name="mxMsg"> 
        <str/> 
      </arr> 
      <arr name="content"> 
        <str/> 
      </arr> 
      <long name="version">1454004358166347776</long>
    </doc>
</result>
```

The text in the BLOB field is simply not getting indexed.

Comment: Could you check and reformat the content of your data-config.xml you posted here? There are several wrong passages in it, like `OracleDriver"url` being one word or the second `</entity>` at the bottom, which is wrong there ...

Comment: I have edited the data-config.xml.The same configuration works with a simple binary BLOB field but not when the excel contents are stored in the BLOB.

Comment: After indexing when I query,the out put shows something like this :              <result name="response" numFound="1" start="0">
     <doc>
    <arr name="message">
      <str>oracle.sql.BLOB@121c39fa</str>
    </arr>
    <int name="id">992</int>
    <arr name="mxMsg">
      <str/>
    </arr>
    <arr name="content">
      <str/>
    </arr>
    <long name="_version_">1454004358166347776</long></doc>
</result>
</response> The text in the BLOB field is simply not getting indexed.